# Inspect element attributes with Google Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

Although the Google Chrome developer tools show the *properties* of a selected element, it doesn't list the attributes.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under properties, click the top expandable menu. It should have all the attributes.

Comment: Aha. So the set of attributes is a property! Is that correct?

Comment: Not exactly. There have been a few questions and discussions about this today though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588846/when-to-access-the-attribute-vs-the-property and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Answer (score 0):

Just right click on the element you want to inspect and choose "Inspect element".
In the bottom panel select Elements tab. It will show the DOM element with the attribures in the form of HTML.

Answer (score 0):

- Open **Inspect Element** by right clicking on the element or any other way you want.
- Find the element you want to add the attribute in.
- Right click on the attribute in **Inspect Element**. Click **Add Attribute**

[image]