# How to get id's of multiple divs on clicking one div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following code

```
<div id = "fa10_holder">
<div id = "b-1"></div>
</div>
```

I am adding this dynamically in a div that holds all of these type of divs ..
lets say if I add another div it would be like this

```
<div id = "fa11_holder">
<div id = "b-2"></div>
</div>
```

Now the problem is when I click the div with id of b-1 or b-2 and so on I want the id of its parent like fa10_holder and the id of the clicked div aswell... can any one help me ??

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Like this working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/km2yj7r8/)** another way.

APIs:

- `parents` - http://api.jquery.com/parents/
- `attr` or `prop` - http://api.jquery.com/attr/ or http://api.jquery.com/prop/

I have added extra class, in case you have many `div` you can have a blanket click via class. `:)`

Extra: [When to access the attribute (vs the property)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588846/when-to-access-the-attribute-vs-the-property)

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".hulk").click(function () {
        alert($(this).parents('div').attr('id'));
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
```

**html**

```
<div id = "fa11_holder"> parent
<div id = "b-2" class="hulk">hulk</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent !! now there is only one thing left what if there is a textarea with an id = "some_id" below the div id = "b-2" how can I get the id of the textarea as well thanks in advance :)

Comment: Glad it helped you @UzumakiNaruto `:)` , Try `.next` Api with $(this) element, also checkout how the .next actually works form query documentation.

Answer (score 1):

```
var thisid = this.id;
var parrentid = $(this).parent().attr('id');
```